# Breadcrumb network using Xbee and Rapberry

Tags: python, gps, xbee

I am stuck at a very unusual problem while trying to make a breadcrumb network, where a breadcrumb is made using RaspberryPi and Xbee. In this application, each Xbee send its data to another Xbee and similarly forward towards the Coordinator. I am trying to make a breadcrumb network of 10 Xbees with almost zero success. I am using puthon xbee library for coing. I am attaching GPS modules to all raspberryPi and my trying to send the GPS data of all the Router Nodes to the Coordinator nodes. I am using the API mode. Since this website has so many genius users, please tell is it possible to make a breadcrumb network or i am pursuing a wrong logic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you gotten working so far?  Can you set up a network with a single router and coordinator and deliver GPS messages between the two?  Start small and build up from there.

Comment: Sir, i tried with 3 routers and 1 coordinator. In each router, i have 3 threads. First thread get data from gps, 2nd threads broadcast data from gps and third thread is getting data from other router and broadcasting it. When i do this, 1st and 2nd thread works and the third thread rarely works. I am able to know this how the data is moving because of RSSI value, because when data goes directly to Coordinator, there is only one RSSI value attached to it. But if it goes to some router and again broadcasted, there are two or more RSSI values attached to it. Please give me some idea sir.